# How to lower case entire column data in Google Cloud BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find a "quick" way to lower case all the data (strings) in a table's column inside Google Cloud BigQuery.

Before going into building a script, I'm looking for more shorter way like Query.

How can I query BigQuery to lower case entire column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out my self. it can be done using UPDATE as Elliott suggested. but it must use standartSQL. I used the `#standardSQL` declration for that.

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE dataset.table
SET field = LOWER(field)
WHERE TRUE
```

Comment: If Elliott's answer helped you please consider upvoting and/or accepting his answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET string_column = LOWER(string_column)
WHERE true;
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I query BigQuery to lower case entire column?

Definitely [LOWER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lower) is the function to use
For example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 
    'https://stackoverflow.com/q/44970976/5221944' AS url, 
    'How to lower case entire column data in Google Cloud BigQuery' AS title
)
SELECT * REPLACE(LOWER(title) AS title) 
FROM `dataset.table`
```

> I am trying to find a "quick" way to lower case all the data

From what I see in your question  - I would not recommend using DML's [UPDATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement) as it is [Costly](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#pricing) and not necessarily "quick" and for sure not flexible in case if you later will want to change your mind let say to have it [UPPER](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#upper) or somehow differently (camel style for example)

The quick way in your case I see in creating [view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views) like below. It is cheap ($0.00) and flexible to accomodate any logic of transforming columns in original table

```
SELECT * REPLACE(LOWER(title) AS title) 
FROM `dataset.table`
```