# how to list values in a field of a big query table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

this is my code. I want to find data on the vaacine for covid-19, yet I don't know how the vaacine is taged in the filed. how can I list al the values possible that I will be able to chooze what value I am intrested in?

myCODE:

SELECT
COUNT(*) as ArticleCount,
EXTRACT(DATE FROM DateTime) AS DATE,
FROM `gdelt-bq.covid19.onlinenewsgeo`
WHERE
Title like______________
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE asc

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a sample of the data you're querying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yet I don't know how the vaacine is taged in the filed

So you have some **column** having some data (limited set of values).

Then you simply

`select distinct column_name from table_name;`

Then You could group or count where `...where column_name in ('val1', 'val2')`

Tell me if I could help in any other way :)) (or wrongly got Your needs, question to be answered, etc... :) )

**EDIT:**
@Yishai of course title could have variety, multiple of values which are **not limited** as I previously stated.

So, first You could make them `LOWER(...)` [How to lower case entire column data in Google Cloud BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970976/how-to-lower-case-entire-column-data-in-google-cloud-bigquery)

Then, You should split them with " " space for example https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split

Then, UNNEST https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays

Then get DISTINCT :)))

Then, analyze - which keyword is the one wanted by You (or, how many).

Then, see which title(s) (LOWERcased, ofc) contain (having) some values (like, having - any SQL the BigQuery support - but that is easier).

We deconstructed the problem, so You should make it, I hope. :)

Comment: On the other hand You could **remove any characters other than alpha& numeric (and spaces)** from the Title.

Before lowering aka pre-processing (aka **divide**) and on 2nd select (before selecting exact matches You want to later process aka post-process, **conquer**), to ease Your work.

Because "covid-19", "Covid19", "COVID-19," are the same for You.

Comment: @Yishai if You solved the problem, please mark question as answered. This would build my credibility and allow me to help futher with more questions, better. Thanks :)